# SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null when retrieving complex object

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, skia

I am working on an Android project in which I am retrieving a list of Person's and trying to display them. The Person class contains the profilePhoto as String and I am able to see it saved in DB, after retrieving a List of Person, I am able to print it in Log.d. But the Skia thing is cribbing that Factory is null.

I know there are other questions with same subject line, but I am not retriving only image, I am retrieving a List of Persons and image is just a variable in it.

Why am I getting the error :

Image save code :

```
public class AddPhotoForUser extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 22;
    Button BtnSelectImage;
    private ImageView ImgPhoto;
    private static volatile Bitmap photo;
    private static volatile ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    final PersonServiceImpl personService = new PersonServiceImpl();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.upload_user_photo);
        Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
        uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ImgPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userPhotoImageView);
        BtnSelectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.userPhotoButtonSelect);
        BtnSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {

                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't load photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!(v == null)) {
                    uploadImage();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddPhotoForUser.this, RestaurantList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddPhotoForUser.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                            if (!(photo == null)) {
                                ImgPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
                                Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
                                uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't load photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private void uploadImage() {

        if (!(photo == null)) {
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            personService.addUserProfilePhoto(Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT));
        }

    }
}
```

Below is where I get list of Users and tie it to adapter :

```
public class OtherUsers extends Activity {

    private PersonServiceImpl personService = new PersonServiceImpl();

    private static volatile List<RestPerson> restPersonList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final String firstName = "firstname";
    public static final String userImage = "userimage";

    static final String userId = "0";
    ListView listView;
    UserAdapter userAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displayuserlist);

        restPersonList = this.personService.getOtherUsers();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersArrayHashList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (RestPerson restPerson : restPersonList) {
            HashMap<String, String> restDisplay = new HashMap<>();
            restDisplay.put(userId, String.valueOf(restPerson.getUserId()));
            restDisplay.put(firstName, restPerson.getFirstName());
            restDisplay.put(userImage, restPerson.getProfilePhoto());
            usersArrayHashList.add(restDisplay);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.usersdisplaylist);

        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(this, usersArrayHashList);

        listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Item", "wasclicked");
                Long userid = restPersonList.get(position).getUserId();
                Log.d("Userid is ", String.valueOf(userid));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is my adapter :

```
public class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public UserAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userprofiles, null);

        TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        ImageView userImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
        HashMap<String, String> usersList = new HashMap<>();
        usersList = data.get(position);
        username.setText(usersList.get(OtherUsers.firstName));
        byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(usersList.get(OtherUsers.userImage).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        userImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Log.d("Image is ",usersList.get(OtherUsers.userImage));

        return view;
    }


}
```

Notice the Log.d at bottom, which says Image is, it's printing the image, here is the output :

```
08-24 15:55:34.767  28131-28131/internetlegion.com.gradlecheck D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-24 15:55:34.767  28131-28131/internetlegion.com.gradlecheck D/Image is﹕ ImlWQk9SdzBLR2dvQUFBQU5TVWhFVWdBQUFLQUFBQUI0Q0FJQUFBRDZ3RzQ0QUFBQUEzTkNTVlFJ
    Q0FqYjRVL2dBQUFFSkVsRVFWUjRcbm5PMmRRV3ZjUmhpR3YyODBhMHpCeDlCZ3JVOU9RdWlsbElE
    c2t3Mmg1NURrdi9nSGhmNk4zTHNTZFVySUtjZUVGWmdlQzZYQkhzM1hcblE0SnRnck1hN1VycTV0
    WDczTHorOU02c0hxMW04Vmd6dXJ1N0syMFVSWEYwZE5SYWRrMVZWV1ZacHRjemY3aDhsMzRZK1I2
    aFlIQW9cbkdCd0tCb2VDd2FGZ2NDZ1lIQW9HaDRMQm9XQndLQmdjQ2dhSGdzRkpGYXlxblhMTnJG
    TTk4d2ZLMTdPenM5YnFxcW9XaTBWNkcwVlJcbkhCOGZwNzhINWcrWDd4T1A2ZVVLVlFsWGJtZldT
    SFJCN1hiVFRqWHJFdS9NVkNTMVM0MTZMeGJVMUx4SVREa0U1aE9jS3JnWG91ejRcbkdFV2ptak85
    T2RHbThmYVByWFN0OTNiWnFJaDVsV0FUKzlveHFtQ1ZxQ2JCK2N5Q2l6Y25XaHZUeHRJdlVoY2xN
    MDMvRUZqVUtEcXpcbjJNaU9hT2pjNysrWmNRV2JSQ2Zld3FQelAzOTZjMzc5K25NUithSDlQNGR1
    ZVBkVzNyMU5MMzhtNG5kMmczTy9oY3RYMC9JNzd2M0tcblZOU2ltTk51QTlDbU9KSG9vaHUzMFMx
    aFdnUFNCS0ZnY0NnWUhBb0doNExCb1dCd0tCZ2NDZ2FIZ3NGSi9WUGxHck1mS3c3cE9qZlNcbkk0
    bHZaSFgvMTQ0ZFAxOFBEdzlicS9NOFB6ZzRTRzlqdVZ6V2RmMk5YMGFKK3ZMVHB4Zi8vcFBhMlg2
    SUZyTS9IajhzSHp4c0xWM1pcbi96dm85Znowbk85VFdzcnpmSDkvUDcxRGRWMnZFS3ptL3ZaZVpw
    MG1nSHRBVmZmMjl2SThiNjFjMmY4NzZQWDg5SnpQTVJnY0NnYUhcbmdzR2hZSEFvR0J3S0JvZUN3
    YUZnY0NnWUhBb0doNExCb1dCd0tCaWMvK0g1WUxNT2p5SDF5TkR6cjhOMVpwTjhQVDA5N2IwM0t6
    c1VcbjFkelRpNHRmLzdyb21ya1pVY3kvdm4vdjlZLzNVNm83bmRCZXowL1ArYjRvaXRicU5kWTMv
    blpzVkhQNStibU1MVmhFcEs3cjZzUEhcbjFyS1YvYitEWHM5UHova2NnOEdoWUhBb0dCd0tCb2VD
    d2FGZ2NDZ1luRkVYWVRGeHN4aXZzczhySUhWWUIybERuTm1WeTJaeGlsZnpcbnlNc29oZUM4bU1p
    WE5jbEdJcWhrRmt5RFNTYlNqTmJ1TmpDcVlCRXhFVy9CSkd1NnJHUzJPU29Xbk5QbWNzeEd0NEZ4
    YjlFcUxrcHdcbjd2MlRuOTgvK2VYNjliSXN5N0ljYnEzSHNpd1gxZStaQmRQSjNhVkhmY09mVnpC
    VSs3cGRWUjEwTmtaVm5XU21NdWJBdnlWTTdvcWVcbkdrTUpIbnJHbC9tSitVbVBqNXBaeWxPWHQx
    a3VsK25GekI4dVg3bC9NSFkreDJCd0tCZ2NDZ2FIZ3NHaFlIQW9HQndLQm9lQ3dhRmdcbmNDZ1lI
    QW9HaDRMQm9XQndLQmdjQ2dZbmRZTm9tUG5ScWVYekV3d09CWU5Ed2VCUU1EZ1VEQTRGZzBQQjRG
    QXdPQlFNRGdXRFE4SGdcblVEQTRGQXdPQllORHdlQ2tiaEE5bjgvVFE5ZllBSm41QStXbmJoQTlu
    OC9UMXoxWll3Tms1ZytVbjNxTFhtTlYrVTR3ZjZCOGpzSGdcblVEQTRGQXdPQllORHdlQlFNRGdV
    REE0RmcwUEI0RkF3T0JRTURnV0RROEhnNk1uSlNWSWR5b2JKVTh2M0tVOGlWMVcxV0N5RzJ4V0Zc
    bitjUGxwOTZpdDNhUGV1YXZ6dWNZREE0RmcwUEI0RkF3T0JRTXpuL0JHYWM2TGpKdUpRQUFBQUJK
    UlU1RXJrSmdnb2xRVGtjTkNob0tcbkFBQUFEVWxJUkZJQUFBQ2dBQUFBZUFnQ0FBQUErc0J1T0FB
    QUFBTnpRa2xVQ0FnSTIrRlA0QUFBQXBWSlJFRlVlSnp0M1RGdTJsQWNcbmdIRS9aQVVXeG9wSWpK
    eWdqZ1FiM0tBOUNXd3NQUVpzNlhXYVNraHBlZ2xRbEhTT2xNbXZReVRVRkR2d0t1SEtYNzdmeURO
    L3JIekJcblVXUWJ3bks1ektxczErdkt4K3ZNNS9PazdaM2Z6UHhPMGhTMWpvSGhEQXhuWURnRHd4
    a1l6c0J3WVRRYVZTNU1KcE9rUVp2TkptbDdcbjV6Y3pQOS90ZHBVTHcrRXc2UVhxNXRSeGZqUHpQ
    VVRER1JqT3dIQUdoak13bklIaDhwTzNMTE9zY3plNHV4M2NWaTUzdjNhVFh2ZzZcbnV6NjZUUXhs
    aUZtSStkV3ZqMG5EdGVjN0dNN0FjQWFHTXpDY2dlRU1ER2RndURDZFRxc1hRbmo5UUJsamVMeDZ2
    Qy91RzlpdEYvdi9cbmd3Yy9Qd3grWENZOTkyRC9qNzFXak1qNWVkMko1WU1McjhzWXc4WGxSYWY0
    RDIvNjdYYjdhZkk1NlNsdHVURDkzUFBiY1loTy9YWFdcblhqc0M2NThaR003QWNBYUdNekNjZ2VF
    TURHZGdPQVBER1JqT3dIQUdoak13M09tM2o1WXhodWYrODFQMjFNQnUvYVhmNzFOdjd6ejNcbi9O
    RHRWbCt3dmxnc1hqOXc1TUwzYy9qend2ZHZYMjZTbm51dy8wZXNWaXZrL0x3dHAxclB2Wi9VK2Y0
    TmhqTXduSUhoREF4bllEZ0Rcbnd4a1l6c0J3Qm9Zek1KeUI0UXdNWjJDNDB6OG5xNU5sV2ZGUUZB
    OUY1Zks1YjZlOHliNG5iYThYZWQwUHVpMzN2enIvN2ZrZW91RU1cbkRHZGdPQVBER1JqT3dIQUdo
    ak13bklIaERBeG5ZRGdEd3hrWXpzQnd0ZWVEVXovZk9KWHptNW52RjBURDUvc0YwZkQ1L2cyR016
    Q2NcbmdlRU1ER2RnT0FQREdSak93SEFHaGpNd25JSGhEQXhuWURnRHc0WFpiRmE1UVAzQzVQYzJQ
    eCtQeDVVTGJibkIyZmx2ei9jUURXZGdcbk9BUERHUmpPd0hBR2hqTXduSUhoREF4bllEZ0R3eGtZ
    enNCd0JvYno5bEg0L05EcjlTb1hxT2RIMzl0OEQ5RndCb1l6TUp5QjRRd01cbloyQTRBOE1aR003
    QWNBYUdNekNjZ2VFTURQY2JUQ1lhZzYwTHNwNEFBQUFBU1VWT1JLNUNZSUk9XG4i
08-24 15:55:34.767  28131-28131/internetlegion.com.gradlecheck D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
08-24 15:55:34.767  28131-28131/internetlegion.com.gradlecheck D/Image is﹕ ImlWQk9SdzBLR2dvQUFBQU5TVWhFVWdBQUFLQUFBQUI0Q0FJQUFBRDZ3RzQ0QUFBQUEzTkNTVlFJ
    Q0FqYjRVL2dBQUFFSkVsRVFWUjRcbm5PMmRRV3ZjUmhpR3YyODBhMHpCeDlCZ3JVOU9RdWlsbElE
```

So what on earth should I do with SkiaImageFactory thing. Any help would be nice. Please note, I am not retrieving single images, I am retrieving entire Person class from server.

Comment: Try to get your full string for image and use some online converter to check is it will convert to image. If it isn't than you have problem with encoding

Comment: @Beyka Can you suggest me how I can remedy this? I have posted code on how I am saving image and all.